# query is not executing

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone help me to fix this query?
I dont know what error i have made. Please help me out..

```
insert into docs values('"$_POST['inputString']"','"$_POST['inputStringa']"','"$_POST['inputStringa1']"','"$_POST['inputStringa2']"','"$_POST['inputStringa3']"','"$_POST['inputStringa4']"')" ;
```

Comment: Please show any errors you get and the actual, generated SQL query. And your query is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749588/protect-against-sql-injection)

Comment: maybe it's time to accept an answer! otherwise you won't get much help for your next question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing "." in the query

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO docs VALUES('".$_POST['inputString']."','".$_POST['inputStringa']."','".$_POST['inputStringa1']."','".$_POST['inputStringa2']."','".$_POST['inputStringa3']."','".$_POST['inputStringa4']."')";
```

or use

for remove vulnerablities

```
mysql_query("insert into docs values ( ' { $_POST['inputString'] }' ,'{$_POST['inputStringa']}',' {$_POST['inputStringa1']}','{$_POST['inputStringa2']}',
'{$_POST['inputStringa3']}','{$_POST['inputStringa4']}')") ;
```

Answer (score 4):

Your quotes are not right. Single quotes and double quotes are getting mixed up. Do it like this:

```
mysql_query("insert into docs
values('{$_POST['inputString']}','{$_POST['inputStringa']}',
'{$_POST['inputStringa1']}','{$_POST['inputStringa2']}',
'{$_POST['inputStringa3']}','{$_POST['inputStringa4']}')") ;
```

Also, remember to pass through all the `POST` variables through `mysql_real_escape_string` like this:

```
$_POST['inputString'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inputString']);
```

Do this BEFORE running the query.

Answer (score 3):

Read the PHP manual entry on strings and learn the basic syntax, you'll discover why this code doesn't work:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 1):

you use both single quote and double quotes, you cant do that. You need to concatenate the post values like so:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO docs VALUES('".$_POST['inputString']."','".$_POST['inputStringa']."','".$_POST['inputStringa1']."','".$_POST['inputStringa2']."','".$_POST['inputStringa3']."','".$_POST['inputStringa4']."')";

mysql_query($sql);
```