# How to use $_GET securely?

Tags: php, mysql, security

I need to use a get function to retrieve $title variable from a url.

```
$title=$_GET["title"];
```

The $title is later used in a MySQL query.

The question is how to make this secure?
In other words, how to neutralize any malicious codes sent through the URL.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sanitize+php

Comment: Have a look at this questin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749588/protect-against-sql-injection

Answer (score 5):

(For a value of "secure" equal to "to prevent it breaking the database"): use any database API that uses [bound parameters](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html).

Bound parmeters tend to let the database handle the escaping (so uses escaping routines written by the database authors rather then the language authors) and uses a syntax that is less prone to being forgotten about for that one vital escape then manually escaping each piece of input data with (for example) `mysql_real_escape_string`.

You might need to take other steps later before you do something with the data in a different context (e.g. to make it safe to insert into an HTML document)

Answer (score 1):

You must use mysql_real_escape_string() to escape all characters that could interfere with you database. If you're displaying this title, you should also make use of htmlentities() or striptags()

Answer (score 1):

As of PHP 5.2, you can use filter_input() and filter_input_array() to sanitize and validate the the $_GET or $_POST data.

For example:

```
$my_string = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'my_string', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Read more about that in this article [here](http://www.phparch.com/2010/07/never-use-_get-again/).

For SQL queries, it's very recommended that you use PDO with prepared statements to protect from SQL injections. You can read about PDO in the PHP Manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql_real_escape_string function (Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement)

[Php Manuel](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use query parameters. There is a number of different ways to connect to mysql from PHP, and they way to use parameters varies a little from framework to framework. Here is an example using PDO:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=127.0.0.1', 'username', 'password');
$sth = $dbh->prepare("select * from table where title = :title")
$sth->execute(array(':title' => $_GET["title"]));
$rows = $sth->fetchAll();

var_dump($rows);
```