# How can I protect my site from SQL injection?

Tags: php, sql, code-injection, host

as you can see I have an error in my site:

[image]

and I alrady put the @:

```
$q = @$_GET['q'];
```

Comment: Don't use warning suppression.

Comment: Putting `@` in your code does **not** solve any issues. If you want to prevent SQL injection, escape your queries properly and/or consider using parameterized queries. See this question for [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Use parameterized queries.  That solves almost the entire problem.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Use `mysqli_real_escape_string($q);`

Comment: Or see here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749588/protect-against-sql-injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$q` is used in a SQL query you need to handle it properly.

But to display in-page with `echo` or equivalent use `htmlentities($q)`[1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) for that part.