# redirect to a content page when a link is clicked

Tags: php

ive just started PHP and MYSQL, and been trying to figure out how i can redirect to a **page** and display the content.

i have this PHP code that lists all my topic rows from my database

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    echo '<a href="#"><p class="list" st>' . $row['topic'] . '<br /></a>';
    }
```

it will list all the topics inside the `<a href>` markup.

when link is clicked, i will be redirected to a page where the content is displayed based on the topic link.

i just need the logic how to create that page. basically i have **page.php** which i plan to put the logic. but i dont know how to start.

Comment: Why don't you also add a `link` field in your database to store the links of pages for each link and put it in the `href` instead of redirect.

Comment: where do you store your topic link address? or how do you define links to topics?

Comment: By the way.. your HTML is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use `GET` method to send `ID` of content to your **page.php** , url should be something like this :

```
  http://site.com/page.php?id=120
```

And in your **page.php** get the id using `$_GET['id']`,i admit you have content in database , so you will display data based on this id.

**PHP code :**

```
   while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
      echo '<a href="page.php?id='.$id.'"><p class="list" st>' . $row['topic'] . '<br /></a>';
    }
```

An important thing , pay attention to **sql injection** especially when you get id.

**Useful links about protecting from SQL injection:**

-[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

-[What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php)

-[Protect against SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749588/protect-against-sql-injection)

Comment: oh, so thats how you do it.. so i use GET to identify the ID  and display the appropriate content for that ID. how clever :) thanks. also, sorry for my ignorance, if i use GET, how do i protect myself from those sql injections?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially each link is going to need to carry a piece of information to `page.php` in order to tell that page what content to display.  This is likely going to be some sort of identifier for the specific record.  Something like this:

```
echo '<a href="page.php?id=' . $row['ID'] . '"><p class="list" st>' . $row['topic'] . '<br /></a>';
```

This will make each link unique with an `id` parameter.  Then, in the code on `page.php` you would check for that parameter as a query string value, which would be available here:

```
$_GET['id']
```

Remember that users can spoof this value and essentially put whatever they want into that link, so make sure it's a valid ID and make sure you don't use it directly in a database query without sanitizing the input first, otherwise users will have an open door to your database.  (Read up on SQL Injection for more information.)

With that value, `page.php` will query the database for the one record which matches that ID and display the data from that record accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
echo '<a href="page.php?topic="'.$row['topic'].'><p class="list" st>' . $row['topic'] . '<br /></a>';
}
```

in the page.php make functions of one topic each and call that respective function for which the request has come